# launch Youtube channel on your App Swift Code

Tags: iphone, swift, video, youtube, ios8

I have spent some days to find the Swift code for youtube Channel to open from my app. but i couldn't find At all, can some one help me please!!
 i need the Code in Swift.

Answer (score 8):

> Update for Swift 3 and iOS 10+

OK, here is how to do it in Swift 3. Basically, there are two easy steps to achieve this:

First, you have to modify `Info.plist` to list `Youtube` with `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes`. Simply open `Info.plist` as a Source Code, and paste this:

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>youtube</string>
</array>
```

After that, you can open any youtube URL inside Youtube application by simply substituting `https://` with `youtube://`. Here is a complete code, you can link this code to any button you have as an Action:

```
@IBAction func YoutubeAction() {

    let YoutubeUser =  "Your Username"
    let appURL = NSURL(string: "youtube://www.youtube.com/user/\(YoutubeUser)")!
    let webURL = NSURL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/user/\(YoutubeUser)")!
    let application = UIApplication.shared

    if application.canOpenURL(appURL as URL) {
        application.open(appURL as URL)
    } else {
        // if Youtube app is not installed, open URL inside Safari
        application.open(webURL as URL)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this suits your purpose:

```
var url  = NSURL(string: "https://youtube.com/your-channel")

if UIApplication.sharedApplication().canOpenURL(url!) == true  {
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(url!)
}
```

Comment: Dear Luca, Thanks for Respond but It is a webURL. i am looking something just like this link " https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5SUV1YY2yxQ "  this guy did with objective C but i am looking the Swift one.

Comment: I can't find anything about youtube channel in this video. Can you post what you've tried so far?

Comment: NSString *channelName = @"TheNameOfTheChannel";

NSURL *linkToAppURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"youtube://user/%@",channelName]];
NSURL *linkToWebURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/user/%@",channelName]];

if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:linkToAppURL]) {
    // Can open the youtube app URL so launch the youTube app with this URL
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:linkToAppURL];
}
else{
    // Can't open the youtube app URL so launch Safari instead
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:li